# J2ME UDP Client cannot send packets under emulator

Tags: java-me, udpclient

I am developping UDP client under J2ME. For long time, every think was fine; 
- the UDP client communicates with the UDP server (the server has a public IP address);
- UDP client works perfectly from J2ME emulator and from a real phone having Internet connection.

Then suddenly the UDP client, under the emulator, is no more able to send packets to any public IP address (but sending to 127.0.0.1 is ok). Please note that UDP client, under real mobile phone, is still able to communicate with the UDP server.

At the same time:
- UDP client under emulator can communicate with the UDP server using localhost (127.0.0.1) address.
- I ran UDP client demos under the emlator, but none of them is able to send packets to public IP addresses (however, every think is fine when using localhost address as the destination address).
- UDP server under emulator is able to send packets to any public address.

To conclude: every think was fine. But know, UDP client cannot send packets under the emulator. The problem is not related to the code since I used the demo.

These are the symptoms. I wish you could help me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You say that "UDP server under emulator is able to send packets to any public address".  Is this correct?  The UDP server app, running on same emulator, is able to *send* UDP packets?

Comment: that right, the UDP server app, running on same emulator, is able to send UDP packets to any public IP address.

Comment: But different emulator instances, right?  You'd need to have two running to have a functional client/server system. Have you tried shutting down the emulator and rebooting your computer, to clear and reset the emulator?  J2ME emulators have a history of being flaky.  You can also try switching which is client and which is server.  You will also need to check which ports the emulators bind to, and make sure that both are open in both firewall and antivirus (which sometimes has rules to block outgoing communication on non-standard ports, which IIRC J2ME emulators use).

Comment: Thanks. I did all the tests using one single emulator instance. I do not need two running because I am sending UDP packets which are sent asynchronously. Besides, UDP client can send data to 127.0.0.1. But when it sends to public IP, I got IO exception with the following message: "failed to send datagram". However, UDP server can send packets to any IP address (local or public). Yes, I shut down my computer. This did not change anything. I cannot switch client-server since I am using one single emulator instance at a time. I do not have antivirus, and I shut down the firwall during the test.